# How do i create a drop down like menu similar to the Facebook drop down notifications

Tags: javascript, drop-down-menu

I am planning to create a drop down menu for my site similar to the DB drop down for notifications  Any JS library help will be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Read about [suckerfish](http://www.htmldog.com/articles/suckerfish/dropdowns/)
Modify it to show on click instead of mouseover
Load the content on show with AJAX
Profit!